# Python: packing an ip address as a ctype.c_ulong() for use with DLL

Tags: python, dll, ip-address, ctypes

given the following code:

```
import ctypes    
ip="192.168.1.1"
thisdll = ctypes.cdll['aDLL']
thisdll.functionThatExpectsAnIP(ip)
```

how can I correctly pack this for a DLL that expects it as a c_ulong datatype?

I've tried using:

```
ip_netFrmt = socket.inet_aton(ip)
ip_netFrmt_c = ctypes.c_ulong(ip_netFrmt)
```

however, the `c_ulong()` method returns an error because it needs an integer.

is there a way to use `struct.pack` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inet_aton returns a string of bytes.  This used to be the *lingua franca* for C-language interfaces.

Here's how to unpack those bytes into a more useful value.

```
>>> import socket
>>> packed_n= socket.inet_aton("128.0.0.1")
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack( "!L", packed_n )
(2147483649L,)
>>> hex(_[0])
'0x80000001L'
```

This unpacked value can be used with ctypes.  The hex thing is just to show you that the unpacked value looks a lot like an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

First a disclaimer: This is just an educated guess.

an ip-address is traditionally represented as four bytes - i.e. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, but is really a unsigned long. So you should convert the representation 192.168.1.1 to an unsiged int. you could convert it like this.

```
ip="192.168.1.1"
ip_long = reduce(lambda x,y:x*256+int(y), ip.split('.'), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but this works:

```
>>> ip = "192.168.1.1"
>>> struct.unpack('>I', struct.pack('BBBB', *map(int, ip.split('.'))))[0]
3232235777L
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more thorough way of handling IPs (v6, CIDR-style stuff etc) check out how it's done in [py-radix](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-radix/), esp. [prefix_pton](http://anoncvs.mindrot.org/index.cgi/py-radix/radix.c?revision=1.17&view=markup).