# How to convert ip address to DWORD?

Tags: python, ip-address, dword

Hey, how can I convert ip address to DWORD using python ?

I searched a while but didn't found anything useful.

Thanks for the helpers!

Comment: There is a perfectly good library call for this.  `struct.inet_pton`.  You should use it instead of rolling your own parser.

Comment: ...unless you're using Windows.  It's not in the socket library on that platform.  inet_aton is, however.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317531/python-packing-an-ip-address-as-a-ctype-c-ulong-for-use-with-dll (for example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python doesn't have a DWORD type. If you need it as a 4-byte string use:

```
struct.pack('bbbb', *(int(x) for x in '127.0.0.1'.split('.')))
```

Comment: And if the endian-ness is out of whack, would you do reverse('127.0.0.1'.split('.')) ?

Comment: No, I'd just use `[::-1]` on the resultant string.

Comment: I would make `struct` handle the endianness issues.

Comment: After thinking about this, I'm going to have to vote you down.  Writing your own parsers when the library has a perfectly good parser is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Don't roll your own solution.  Use the `socket` library.

```
import socket
socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, "127.0.0.1")
```

It will throw exceptions when it can't properly parse the address, and writing your own parsers for things is just a recipe for problems down the line.

Doing it this way also makes it easier to transition your code to IPv6.  And writing your own address parser for IPv6 would be a really bad idea because IPv6 addresses are complex and have some weird corner cases.

**Edit:** Apparently, this doesn't work on Windows.  I'm not sure how you're supposed to parse IPv6 addresses on Windows, but there is still a library call that can parse IPv4 addresses.  It's `socket.inet_aton`, and you should use it if `socket.inet_pton` doesn't exist instead of rolling your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a correct IPv4, you could do this, for example:

```
import struct

ip = "192.168.2.101"
components = map(int, ip.split("."))
asLittleEndianDword = struct.pack("<I", (components[0] << 24) |
                                        (components[1] << 16) |
                                        (components[2] << 8) |
                                        components[3])
```